# Adding a global shadow in Navigation Bar

Tags: swift, xcode, uikit, uinavigationbar, appdelegate

I would like to ask how can I add a global shadow in my navigation Bar.
I tried several methods that I've seen here in stack but some of them are not working. Some of the codes shows a shadow and color but the background is affected to the change.

this is the code that I most saw when I research how to solve it but its not working. the nav bar shadow is not changing at all. I'm putting it in the App delegate.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlf6V.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not post images of code or errors. Text is preferred so that we can try to reproduce the problem without having to re-type everything and your question can be properly indexed or read by screen readers.